# Can changing an access specifier in a program change the behaviour of the program?

Tags: c++, c++11

I wonder is there any cases in a C++ program wherein changing an access specifier (public/protected/private) in the code lead to a change in the behaviour of that program?

Comment: you mean in the case where both versions of the code would compile without errors, right?

Comment: @user463035818 exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One interesting example that essentially happens purely at runtime, meaning a program needs to somehow know some information derived from access level: Per [[except.handle]/3.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/except.handle#3), an exception handler matches an exception object if the handler accepts an unambiguous and **public** base class of the exception object's class type.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {};

void test(void (*thrower)()) {
    try {
        thrower();
    } catch (Base&) {
        std::cout << "Caught a Base." << std::endl;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Not a Base?" << std::endl;
    }
}

class D1 : public Base {};
class D2 : private Base {};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Test D1" << std::endl;
    test([]() { throw D1{}; });
    std::cout << "Test D2" << std::endl;
    test([]() { throw D2{}; });
}
```

This prints:

```
Test D1
Caught a Base.
Test D2
Not a Base?
```

... even though the only difference between `D1` and `D2` is a change of an access specifier keyword.

Comment: Woww, what is the reason behind this?

Comment: If you mean why was it specified this way, I'd guess it's mainly because non-public inheritance does not model an "is-a" relationship.

Answer (score 4):

Templates allow you to do different things depending on whether a member or method is accesible or not. Just as a random example, consider this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct foo_private {
    private:
        foo_private() {}
};
struct foo_public {
    public:
        foo_public() {}
};

int main() {        
    std::cout << std::is_default_constructible<foo_private>::value;
    std::cout << std::is_default_constructible<foo_public>::value;       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can happen if someone SFINAE'd off of calling that function. For example:

```cpp
class Cat {
public:
    void purr() const;

public:
    void hiss() const;
};

using prefer_overload_t = int;
using backup_overload_t = long;

template <typename T>
auto react(prefer_overload_t, T const& t)
    -> decltype(t.purr())
{
    return t.purr();
}

template <typename T>
void react(backup_overload_t, T const& t)
{
    t.hiss();
}

int main() {
    Cat cat;
    react(prefer_overload_t{}, cat);
}
```

[Live on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/NaYv8z).

If the `purr` function has public accessibility, this calls `cat.purr()`.
If the `purr` function has non-public accessibility, this calls `cat.hiss()`.